# Media Queries breakpoints clarification

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I've setup these breakpoints

```
    X-Small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) 
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

 Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px) 
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px) 
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

 Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px) 
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    body {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

 X-Large devices (large desktops, less than 1400px) 
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
    body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Why if I try to resize the screen the colour is always yellow and doesn't change according with the breakpoints?

Comment: because `max-width: 1400px` is also true for smaller screens. Either place the larger screens at top so that the queires for smaller screens overwrite the value or use `@media (min-width: value) and (max-width: value) { ... }`

Comment: You need to define decrement order of `@media (max-width: ...)` like `1400px` then `1200px`  then `992px` and so on... Then It will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `max-width: 1400px` is also true for smaller screens. Either place the larger screens at top so that the queires for smaller screens overwrite the value or use `@media (min-width: value) and (max-width: value) { ... }`

Starting with the largest to the smallest screen:

```css
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Using the `and`-keyword:

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 577px)
  and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px)
  and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 993px)
  and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px)
  and (max-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```